# Pytest - Running test foo any number of times after one or more tests

Tags: pytest

I have a test like this -

```
class TestMyUsefulTest:
    # Calling test_foo for the FIRST time
    def test_foo_1(self, my_fixture):
        # do something in the test method
        assert 0 == 0  # I am asserting something in my test

    def test_bar(self, my_fixture):
        # do something in the test method
        assert 0 == 0  # I am asserting something in my test

    # Calling test_foo for the SECOND time
    def test_foo_2(self, my_fixture):
        # do something in the test method
        assert 0 == 0  # I am asserting something in my test
```

*The second time I call test_foo, I am doing the exact same thing as I did the first time.*

Is there a way to call test_foo, without having to repeat the code again?

Here is the implementation based on @DJanssens' comment -

```
class TestMyUsefulTest:
    def foo(self, a_fixture):
        # do stuff with a_fixture
        assert 0 == 0

    def test_foo_1(self, a_fixture):
        self.foo(a_fixture)

    def test_bar(self, a_fixture):
        assert 0 == 0

    def test_foo_2(self, a_fixture):
        self.foo(a_fixture)
```

Comment: What about creating a test_foo, which calls twice a function foo() in which you do the thing you want repeated and asserted? I think I'm not completely understanding your question.

Comment: `def test_foo(self, my_fixture):` is not a call -- it is a definition

Comment: @DJanssens - Thanks, and I got what you are saying. I essentially want to define a test once, and call it in other places.